# How to get an element from a vec3 object in JS

Tags: javascript, vector

I am writing code to check if a vec3 has certain values in the elements. How do I retrieve a value for an element in vec3?

I have tried using *vec3Name*.Position.a but that does not work for JS.

```
JS
var vector = vec3(10,3,8);

if (vector.Position.a == 10)
  console.log("True");
else
  console.log("False");
```

I am just getting errors for everything I am trying saying that the methods do not exist.

Comment: Where did you get this vec3 function? What kind of library are you using?

Comment: I believe I am using the built-in vec3 function, but I am using WebGLUtils

Comment: There's no built-in vec3 function in javascript, nor WebGLUtils, you seem to be mixing up GLSL shader code and javascript.

Comment: There is a library some class on WebGL uses. It has math library that follows no standard JavaScript convensions. For example it creates new "3 element vectors" with a function called `vec3` rather than a constructor named `Vec3`.  I'm guessing it's [this one](https://github.com/esangel/WebGL/blob/master/Common/MV.js). If that's the case then it would be `vector[0] == 10` which by the way would have been trival to figure out by using the JavaScript console. [Make one and it will be inspectable](https://imgur.com/stMWY89)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in the context you are executing your code you are using some library as there is not vec3 function in Javascript.

Try printing the object structure to the console with:

`console.log(vector)`

...and take a look at the object structure in the developer tools. There you'll find all the properties and methods you can use.